Equivalence between finitely presented additive functors of projective modules and right modules
Let $R$ be a ring with unity. I want to show the following equivalence of categories
$$\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{Proj} R) \cong \operatorname{Mod} R.$$
Here, $\operatorname{R}$ denotes the category of right $R$-modules, $\operatorname{Proj} R$ is the full subcategory of projective right modules and for an additive category $\mathcal{C}$ the category $\operatorname{mod} \mathcal{C}$ denotes the category of additive functors $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathrm{Ab}$.
I thought I had a promising approach using the following functor
$$E:\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{Proj} R) \to \operatorname{Mod} R$$
which is defined as follows. For a finitely presented functor $F \in \operatorname{ob}(\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{Proj} R))$ we have a presentation
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,P_1) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,P_0) \to F \to 0$$
being an exact sequence. This induces a module homomorphism $P_1 \to P_0$ and the functor $E$ maps $F$ to the image of that module homomorphism $\operatorname{Im}(P_1 \to P_0)$, i.e.
$$E(F):= \operatorname{Im}(P_1 \to P_0).$$
Now, let $\eta: F \to G$ be a morphism in $\operatorname{mod}(\operatorname{Proj} R))$. Then we have two presentations
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,P_1) \overset{p}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,P_0) \to F \to 0$$
and
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,Q_1) \overset{q}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,Q_0) \to G \to 0$$
which induces a commutative diagram with vertical arrows in each column, giving morphisms $\phi_0:P_0 \to Q_0$ and $\phi_1:P_1 \to Q_1$. Then, we have a well-defined restriction ${\phi_{0}}_{\mid \operatorname{Im} p}:\operatorname{Im} p \to \operatorname{Im} q$ and we then send
$$E(\eta):= {\phi_{0}}_{\mid \operatorname{Im} p}.$$
I checked that all of this is well-defined and now I want to show the $E$ is faithful and was able to prove that if ${\phi_{0}}_{\mid \operatorname{Im} p} = {\psi_{0}}_{\mid \operatorname{Im} p}$, then $\phi_1=\psi_1$ by projectivity of $P_1$ but still struggle to show $\phi_0=\psi_0$. I also did not have a canonical way of seeing that $E$ is dense or full. So, perhaps this approach was not the right one from the beginning. I would appreciate some help on the construction of the equivalence.

This approach is problematic since it does depend on the choice of a presentation. So functoriality will not be easy (or, in fact, impossible) to prove. But there is a much simpler functor, as explained in my answer.

@MartinBrandenburg Hmm does it really depend on the choice of presentation? Before, I have proven the equivalence $\operatorname{mod}(\mathcal{C}) \cong \mathcal{C}^2/\mathrm{htp}$ where the right hand side category is the category of two-term complexes in $\mathcal{C}$ modulo homotopy. And thus I could take a two-term complex, i.e. the map $P_1 \to P_0$ and this does not depend on a choice.

I didn't know this context, it's not in the post.

Every right $R$-module $M$ induces the additive functor $\hom(-,M)$ on all right $R$-modules, which we can restrict to the projective right $R$-modules. This describes a functor $\mathrm{Mod}(R) \to [\mathrm{Proj}(R)^{op},\mathbf{Ab}]$.
In the other direction, notice that the underlying abelian group of $M$ can be recovered as $\hom(R,M)$. So we define the functor $[\mathrm{Proj}(R)^{op},\mathbf{Ab}] \to \mathrm{Mod}(R)$ by $F \mapsto F(R)$. Indeed $F(R)$ carries the structure of a right $R$-module: There is a ring homomorphism $R \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Proj}(R)}(R)$, $r \mapsto (x \mapsto rx)$, hence a ring homomorphism $R^{op} \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Proj}(R)^{op}}(R) \to \mathrm{End}(F(R))$.
It is easy to check that the composition $\mathrm{Mod}(R) \to [\mathrm{Proj}(R)^{op},\mathbf{Ab}] \to \mathrm{Mod}(R)$ is isomorphic to the identity. For the other one, for every additive functor $F : \mathrm{Proj}(R)^{op} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ with associated right $R$-module $M$ we need to find an isomorphism of functors $\alpha : F \to \hom(-,M)$, so natural isomorphism of abelian groups $\alpha_P : F(P) \to \hom(P,M)$, where $P$ is a projective right $R$-module. Let $p \in P$. This defines a right $R$-linear map $\lambda_p : R \to P$, $r \mapsto pr$, inducing an additive map $F(\lambda_p) : F(P) \to F(R) = M$. Define $\alpha_P(x)(p) := F(\lambda_p)(x)$. One can check that $\alpha_P(x)$ is indeed a right $R$-linear map $P \to M$, so that $\alpha_P : F(P) \to \hom(P,M)$ is well-defined. Naturality in $P$ is also not hard.
By construction, $\alpha_R$ is an isomorphism. Since both sides of $\alpha$ are additive, it follows that the subcategory $\{P : \alpha_P \text{ is isomomorphism}\}$ is closed under finite direct sums and direct summands. Hence, it contains all finitely generated projective modules. This finishes the proof if we work with functors $\mathrm{Proj}_{\mathrm{fg}}(R)^{op} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ on finitely generated projective modules.
The statement is not true for all projective modules. For an infinite set $I$, consider the additive functor $F = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \hom(-,R)$. The associated module is $M = \bigoplus_{i \in I} R$. The canonical morphism $\alpha_P : \bigoplus_{i \in I} \hom(P,R) \to \hom(P,\bigoplus_{i \in I} R)$ is injective, and it is bijective when $P$ is finitely generated, but it is not surjective when $ P = R^{\oplus I}$.
What is true is that $\mathrm{Mod}(R)$ is equivalent to the category of product-preserving additive functors $F : \mathrm{Proj}(R)^{op} \to \mathbf{Ab}$. This means that for every family of projective modules $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ the natural homomorphism $F(\bigoplus_{i \in I} P_i) \to \prod_{i \in I} F(P_i)$ is an isomorphism. In fact, then in the proof above $\{P : \alpha_P \text{ is isomorphism}\}$ will contain every projective module.

Aw man, I had exactly that approach at first but I discarded it because I did not know how to show faithfulness. Anyways, thank you for this extensive answer and the insight given at the end!
